# SQL Rollup Group By Single Column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a dataset consisting of an ApplicationName (ApplicationAlias) and then distinct count of UserName

The user wants a report rolling up (the top 20 of these apps but with the addition of the username count (combined distinct) of all the previous rows.

- Standard Build Apps - 6174
- Standard Build Apps, Adobe Acrobat - 6397
- Standard Build Apps, Adobe Acrobat, Microsoft Office Word - 6605
- Standard Build Apps, Adobe Acrobat, Microsoft Office Word, Microsoft Office Outlook - 6723
- Standard Build Apps, Adobe Acrobat, Microsoft Office Word, Microsoft Office Outlook, Microsoft Office Excel - 6859
  -...  (And So on)

At the moment i can only think of using a set operator with about 20 union all queries with the concatenation as appears above, hardly ideal.

Is there another way?

I Am using SQL Server and its a Single Table of ApplicationAlias and UserName

But there is another spanner in the works in that they *ONLY* want to count users that have the Applications In question, ie any others outside the list (ie Standard Build Apps, Adobe Acrobat, Microsoft Office Word) should not be included.

I'm thinking this is near impossible in SQL or at least can only be done with part statements to gather the data with help from Excel?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[usersApps](
    [UserName] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [ApplicationAlias] [nvarchar](100) NULL
)
```

---

| UserName | ApplicationAlias     |

---

|10008     |Standard Build Apps   |

---

|10008     |Adobe Acrobat         |

---

|10056     |Microsoft Office Word |

---

|10056     |Microsoft Office Excel|

---

|10059     |Symantec PGP Desktop  |

---

Comment: What platform are you using?  Sql server has a `PIVOT` method that might work for you.

Comment: Please edit your question to better explain your table structure. It sounds line you have a table with two columns, app name and user count. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes thats correct (edited question)

Comment: Is the application name comma delimited like that? or is it username fred application word, username fred, application excel... etc?

Comment: No its a single application per row in the column

Comment: Hope that works for you.  I've set up a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1227ee/2) so you can make sure its what you want.  If you need any tweaks, let me know. Good luck!

Comment: So one part is to find top 20 *single* apps, in terms of user count. Then you want to display them in the form of a running total except the total user count should reflect *distinct* users of the applications shown in the row, is that correct? E.g. if Word was the most used app with 5 users and Excel the second one with 4 where 2 used both, then it would go something like `Word, 5; Word+Excel, 7; ...`. Am I on the right track with that?

Comment: Thats right Andy but its *only* those apps listed in the original example, if that user uses any other apps that aren't in the list then it shouldn't be counted.

Answer (score 1):

So, given your recent edit, it looks like you want two columns, comma delimited list of apps and your user.

> "Standard Build Apps, Adobe Acrobat", 10008
>
> "Microsoft Office Word, Microsoft Office Excel", 10056
>
> Symantec PGP Desktop", 10059

If you want to create a comma delimited list in sql, you can do it `FOR XML PATH` and `STUFF`.

```
SELECT apps = 
    STUFF((SELECT ', ' + ApplicationAlias
           FROM usersApps b  
           where b.UserName = a.UserName 
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, ''),
    UserName
FROM usersApps a
GROUP BY UserName
```

See my [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1227ee/2)

If you want to exclude application names, just add a where not in clause.

Comment: Great trick to concatenate fields like "customer note, order note" etc... as well.